# How can I activate an internal page link with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, lightbox, internal-link

How do you activate a link when the page loads using javascript?

I am trying to open a lightbox when the page loads, here is the link I am trying to activate.

```
<a href="#home_video" rel="facebox">Replay Intro</a>
```

Comment: you can use `<>`. You just need to select the code and click the code format button (*the one with the 0s and 1s*)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#linkID").bind('click',function()
    {
    $(this).facebox();
    })
    $("#linkID").click();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: how would i insert this into the head?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
(document).ready(function() {
$("#linkID").bind('click',function()
{
$(this).facebox();
})
$("#linkID").click();
})
</script>

Answer (score 0):

using vanilla javascript that would be to use `window.location.href = 'your_link_here.html'`
Using your lightbox, the code could be different. Please post a link to the lightbox you are using or show us some sample code. Usually they come with API's or documentations on how to use them.

Comment: i have a few other ones that i could use but i didnt see anything about auto loading

Comment: According to the documentation: `jQuery.facebox({ div: '#home_video' });`

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to trigger a 'click' event on the `<a>`?

That would be something like this:

```
$('#home_video').click();
```

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood the meaning of the button, and have checked it in error.